# LibreOffice crashes whenever I try to insert a latex equation in it

Tags: latex, libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice on Windows 7 x64 and downloaded the extention from [here](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/texmaths-1) and normally installed it now I insert the `Pi` key, a window is opened and I paste the following code in it.

```
 \begin{align}
      T_4 &= \langle \underline{k}\,.\,\underline{k}^{*^T} \rangle=
      \left\langle
      \begin{bmatrix}
      \left|k_1\right|^2 & k_1k_2^* & k_1k_3^* & k_1k_4^* \\
      k_2k_1^* & \left|k_2\right|^2 & k_2k_3^* & k_2k_4^* \\
      k_3k_1^* & k_3k_2^* & \left|k_3\right|^2 & k_3k_4^* \\
      k_4k_1^* & k_4k_2^* & k_4k_3^* & \left|k_4\right|^2
      \end{bmatrix}
      \right\rangle
      \\
      &=\frac{1}{2}
      \!\begin{aligned}[t]
      & \left[\begin{matrix}
      \langle|S_{XX}+S_{YY}|^2\rangle &
      \langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &\\
      \langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle &
      \langle|S_{XX}-S_{YY}|^2\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
      \langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle&
      \langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
      \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle &
      \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &
      \end{matrix}\right.\\
      & \left.\begin{matrix}
      & \langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle
      & \langle -j(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
      \cdots\cdots& \langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle
      & \langle -j(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
      \cdots\cdots& \langle|S_{XY}+S_{YX}|^2\rangle
      & \langle-j(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
      & \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle
      & \langle|S_{XY}-S_{YX}|^2\rangle
      \end{matrix}\right]
      \end{aligned}
    \end{align}
```

I also pressed the preamble key and inserted the code `usepackage{geometry}` there.
But finally when I press the latex key to generate the equation, this crash occures.

[image]

It seems that the problem is because of either `LibreOffice` or `texmaths` extension. I want to know if anyone had the same problem before and how did he solve it?

Comment: Open a bug report at bugs.libreoffice.org.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue here on Win 10 LibreOffice 5 using either 0.39 or 0.41 of Texmaths just typing x = 0. I used the suggestion from here http://sourceforge.net/p/texmaths/bugs/52/ however it works once and then starts crashing again. I think we should use the old version of LibreOffice, i.e., 4.3.4.1. Please let me know if you have found some workaround for this issue.

The best of luck,

Vagner